# How to trigger cyclic job in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline in which job configuration is similar to as shown below:

Job 0 triggers Job 1, and then Job 1 triggers Job 2 and Job 4 simultaneously.
Job 4 triggers Job 5 and so on.

```
             Job 0 
               |
             Job 1
              |
           /     \
       Job 2     Job 4
         |         |  
       Job 3     Job 5
                   |
                 Job 6
                   |
                 Job 7
```

Once the entire pipeline finishes, Job 6 and job 7 should get automatically triggered with a different parameter. (Next Parameter to be picked can be determined via shell/conditional step).

Is there any way to achieve this?

How can one job be triggered multiple time serially (without manual intervention)?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "cyclic?" Do you want Job 0 or Job 1 to be triggered at timed intervals? Do you want Job 1 to be triggered after Job 7? Do you want Job 1 to execute again after it completes? Can you add extra lines to your pipeline to show where the cycle occurs?

Comment: Once the entire pipeline completes (ie Job 0 to Job 7 completes), i want Job 6 and Job 7 to get triggered with a different set of parameters. The parameter can be passed through shell or env variable

Comment: Does the parameter for the second build of Job 6 depend on the output of the first build of Job 7?

Comment: No.. Irrespective of the job 7 status, Job 6 should get triggered with different set of parameter